# Java Reflection How to instantiate class field type

Tags: java, reflection

I have the follow class that I'm trying to instantiate through reflection and then auto instantiate it's field 'databaseService'

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

        @AutoInstantiate
        private DatabaseService databaseService;

        @AfterSetup
        public void initialize() {

                System.out.println("Testing " + databaseService.getEntry());

        }
    }
```

My Simple class I'm trying to auto instantiate

```
public class DatabaseService {

    public DatabaseService() {}

    public String getEntry() {

        return "I'm working! ";
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do

```
public class Instantiator {

    private static void start() {

        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com");
        Class<?> clazz = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Controller.class)[0];

         //Assume 'clazz' is 'BaseController' (the parent class of DatabaseService)

        for(Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {

            if(field.isAnnotationPresent(AutoInstantiate.class)) {

                try {

                    field.setAccessible(true);

                    Object autowiredObject = field.getType().newInstance();

                    //HERES WHERE IT ALWAYS FAILS
                    field.set(clazz, autowiredObject);

                }
                catch(Exception e) {

                    logger.severe("Failure invoking class " + clazz.getName() + " Problem : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the simple main

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Instantiator.start();
    }
}
```

Problem
SEVERE: Failure invoking class com.controller.BaseController Problem : Can not set com.service.DatabaseService field com.controller.BaseController.databaseService to java.lang.Class

Overall problem:
I'm not sure how to get the instantiated class Object (DatabaseService) set back it's parent class (BaseController)

Comment: you need to provide object instance to that set method, not type of field.

Comment: @GotoFinal Thank you for your response. I tried several ways and still couldn't get it to work. Could you briefly show show me what that would look like. Much thanks

Comment: Take a look how IoC containers work.

Comment: You can't instantiate object field unless you have a ```BaseController``` object.

Comment: @zhh I removed some lines of code for simplicity of the reader. I updated the code above. Assume 'clazz' here is the BaseController

Comment: clazz is not a BaseController. You need a BaseController. (e.g. ```BaseController bc = new BaseController()``` ), then after you setting the field you are setting the field of ```bc```. This is only valid for one instance, if you have two BaseController instances, you need to set twice. In your code, you don't have any instance.

Comment: @zhh Do I have to explicitly call the type "BaseController"? I was hoping I could do all of this generically for when other types are involved

Comment: It looks like you are not familiar with java reflection, here is a tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your line with problem:

```
field.set(autowiredObject.getClass(), autowiredObject);
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) for the parameters of `Field.set(Object, Object)` method. I quoted a part:

> Parameters:
>
> obj - the object whose field should be modified
>
> value - the new value for the field of obj being modified

(If the field is static, obj should be put `null` instead).

This means that you should actually put the target instance with the same type as `clazz` as the first parameter in the `Field.set(Object, Object)` method, because the target instance you are trying to have the field modified is not the `Class` object of DatabaseService. However, you are missing an instance of any type annotated with `Controller`, or `BaseController`, as you amended later.

Comment: Is this then impossible to do without explicitly calling "BaseController"? I was hoping to do this generically for when other types are introduced

Comment: you can create that type via reflections too, but at the end you need that instance as how it would work otherwise?

Comment: @stackoverflow According to your situation, I think you want the creation of any class annotated with Controller also automatically creates DatabaseService and has it stored in the field databaseService. You can't do that, since you cannot detect invocation of an executable, in other words, constuctor or method. I suggest you to make Controller an abstract class with the field databaseService, and inside the constructor, assign databaseService with a new instance. So anyone inherits Controller will have the databaseService field automatically assigned when their type is being instantiated.

Comment: @RcExtract thank you for you help & advice. much appreciated